# How can I dispose every instance object in StructureMap's ObjectFactory?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, structuremap, ioc-container

I'm using StructureMap in my project and when the application finishes running I need to call the Dispose() method on all of the Singleton instances inside the ObjectFactory that implement IDisposable.

I cannot find anyway to do it via the StructureMap API.

Another thought I had was to get a reference to every instance and call it myself, but I cannot figure out how to loop through all of the instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in another question: [StructureMap Disposing Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443623/structuremap-disposing-container)

```
ObjectFactory.Container.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 2):

PS: You might be interested in the [deterministic disposal](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DeterministicDisposal) by [Autofac IoC container](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)

> Autofac can guarantee that components are disposed of predictably.