# StructureMap Disposing Container

Tags: structuremap

In my application each tenant has it's own StructureMap container.

At runtime, tenant instances may be shutdown or restarted. Is there any tidying up I should do (such as calling IContainer.Dispose) or should I just let Garbage Collection do it's job?

We do have a number of singleton instances that implement IDisposable. Ideally we should call Dispose on these prior to disposing the container. I know this is done automatically on a Nested Container but wasn't sure about a standard container?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call Dispose on your container, which will dispose cached instances for you.

Answer (score 0):

Call dispose on the containers.

You should never "just let the Garbage Collector do its job".  See my response to this post to understand why:

[Is it bad practice to depend on the garbage collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520881/is-it-bad-practice-to-depend-on-the-net-automated-garbage-collector/8419359#8419359)

Comment: I was using StructureMap inside of a TopShelf Windows service and every 2/3 times the deployment would fail and just hang.  It turned out the cause was not disposing of the container.