# Can this While-Foreach loop cause a managed-memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, foreach

I was reading @supercat's post here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10317035 and I had a question regarding the following:

> It's important to note that even objects which only interact with 100% managed objects can do things that need to be cleaned up (and should use IDisposable). For example, an IEnumerator which attaches to a collection's "modified" event will need to detach itself when it is no longer needed. Otherwise, unless the enumerator uses some complex trickery, the enumerator will never be garbage-collected as long as the collection is in scope. If the collection is enumerated a million times, a million enumerators would get attached to its event handler.

I currently have a very very very slow memory leak in my code and I'm having a hell of a time isolating it (it takes at least 12 hours to notice a trend in private memory and at least 3 days at full-steam before it will throw an OutOfMemoryException).  I think it might be related to what @supercat mentioned about internally subscribing to an event, except I am dealing with C# and not VB. In the production code the GC cleans up the memory if the while-loop exits, but not before then.

**In the following code, are there any event handlers getting subscribed to behind the scenes?**

**Does anything in the two loops look like a managed-leak?**

**Does `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` have odd memory-usage behaviour?**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DoForeachWhile_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to begin. Press Escape to stop the program.");
            ConsoleKeyInfo KeyPressed = Console.ReadKey();

            while (KeyPressed.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                IEnumerable<string> SomeIteration = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\"); // new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

                foreach (var StringItem in SomeIteration)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(StringItem);
                }

                //Thread.Sleep(10);
                Console.Clear();

                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                    KeyPressed = Console.ReadKey(true);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit the program.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At the end of a `foreach`, the enumerator will be disposed automatically. However, any objects inside the main collection will not be. That's the coders responsibility.

Comment: I don't have any insight into loop memory leaks, but when it comes to finding those hard to find leaks a tool like [jetBrains dotMemory](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) or [Redgate ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) are worth the price of admission.

Comment: Nothing in the first example will cause a memory leak. In the second example, the enumerator isn't referencing any events on the collection (to my knowledge, `List<T>` doesn't have any events to attach). If there's a memory leak when running that loop, it's almost certainly in one of the methods that your code calls. The `foreach` itself is not the cause of the leak.

Comment: @JimMischel I didn't think so either. I made a minor edit and put the `EnumerateFiles(...)` call back in the test code. I'm going to change my production code a bit anyways to use `GetFiles(...)` which returns a `string[]` and just for-loop through it.  The Docs indicate `EnumerateFiles` can begin before the search is actually finished... I'm just going to avoid the black-magic in the short term and test for the leak again when I have some time.

Comment: I would suggest creating and analyzing a memory dump using `Windbg` or attaching a memory profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running the sample code for a day there was no leak.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, I also don't think there's a memory leak in your loops.

But what about this part: What if `RunningOTS.StartWork(...)` throws an exception? Should you then call `RunningOTS.EndWork(...)` passing a possibly invalid `WorkStartHandle`?

Normally I would write a block like this like

```
try
{
    WorkStartHandle =
        RunningOTS.StartWork(p_waitForStartAcknowledge: true);

    // do {  } while ( )

    RunningOTS.EndWork(WorkStartHandle);
}
finally
{
    Log
        .FormattedLine(MessageScope.Nests,
        "{0} :: RunToken {1}", NestID, RunningOTS);
}
```

However, this may not work for you because I don't know if you might get an exception thrown in your `do while`. It may be that you get an exception thrown by a line *other than* `RunningOTS.StartWork(...)`, and you *do* need to call `RunningOTS.EndWork(...)`.

My best suggestion, then, is to somehow test if `WorkStartHandle` is valid in the `finally` block. Presuming this is a handle like many others,

```
if (WorkStartHandle >= 0) // valid handle?
    RunningOTS.EndWork(WorkStartHandle)
```

...may work.

Comment: It's not an OS handle or anything like that. It's a custom class I implemented and it doesn't really work like that.