# Should I use using statement on JsonConver in return

Tags: c#

I have a new project with existing code.
And I saw that in one method was used a stream without 'using' statement:

```
 private FileInfoRequest ParseFileInfoRequest(Stream body)
        {
            try
            {
                var sr = new StreamReader(body, Encoding.UTF8);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileInfoRequest>(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Error("Could not parse FileInfoRequest", ex);
                throw Thrower.GetThrowError(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    _localization.Api().BadRequestBody,
                    UiMessageKey.ApiBadRequest);
            }
        }
```

Question is: will this stream clear by GC or I need to write something like:

```
            using(sr)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileInfoRequest>(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
```

Comment: You should dispose of the stream. Yes

Comment: This is an interesting read relating to Dispose and it's impact on Garbage Collection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520881/is-it-bad-practice-to-depend-on-the-net-automated-garbage-collector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should always `dispose` the stream when it is no longer needed. Otherwise there might always be a reference left to this stream and the GC will not remove it from memory.

by either wrapping the code in a `using` block or using `sr.Dispose();`.