# Unit testing not using correct mocking class

Tags: unit-testing, structuremap, rhino-mocks

I am using Rhino.Mocks and Structure map to help unit test my code.  I have several tests that pass when they are ran by themselves, but when ran as a group fail to pass.  The setup code for these unit tests is:

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void Setup()
{
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
    {
       x.For(IManager)().Use(Handler)();
    });
}
```

In my tests, I stub out this interface and call the method.

```
[TestMethod]
public void AreMultiple_Test()
{
    var mackIManager = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IManager>();
    mackIManager.Stub(u => u.GetTwoUserName(Arg<int>.Is.Anything)).Return(null);
    ObjectFactory.Inject(typeof(IManager), mackIManager);

    StepAdditionalActionBase actionBase = new StepAdditionalActionBase();
    bool areMultiple = actionBase.AreMultiple(new WorkOrder { Id = "123" });

    Assert.IsFalse(areMultiple);
}
```

Test Method 2

```
[TestMethod]
public void AreMultiple_Test()
{
    var mackIManager = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IManager>();
    mackIManager.Stub(u => u.GetTwoUserName(Arg<int>.Is.Anything)).Return("123");
    ObjectFactory.Inject(typeof(IManager), mackIManager);

    StepAdditionalActionBase actionBase = new StepAdditionalActionBase();
    bool areMultiple = actionBase.AreMultiple(new WorkOrder { Id = "123" });

    Assert.IsTrue(areMultiple);
}
```

This is unit testing the following code.

```
public bool AreMultiple(WorkOrder workOrder)
{
    string secondUser = _handler.GetTwoUserName(_workflowManager.GetNumberForProject(workOrder.Id));
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(secondUser ))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

When I run them by themselves, they work fine.  When I run them together, the first passes and the second fails.  When I debug the second one, I find that that the return value in the Stubbed method is still coming back as null.  How do I get this to use the new Stubbed method.

UPDATE.

I am using StructureMap as my container.  From what I have been able to find, the following code is what is used to dispose of the container I got it from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354354/how-can-i-dispose-every-instance-object-in-structuremaps-objectfactory).  When I added this, the test still fail when ran together, but pass when ran individually.

```
[TestCleanup()]
 public void TestCLeanup()
 {
     ObjectFactory.Container.Dispose();
 }
```

Comment: How do you resolve the `_handler` field?

Answer (score 1):

The tests work one by one but fails if run all together. The problem should be in the *common* part which is being shared across the tests making them dependent from each other. In this particular case that is static `ObjectFactory` which is nothing else but a [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) (anti-pattern).

In the tests, you mock the `IManager` interface and register it in the *ObjectFactory*:

```
ObjectFactory.Inject(typeof(IManager), mackIManager);
```

Then the [SUT](http://xunitpatterns.com/SUT.html) uses the *ObjectFactory* service locator to resolve and use the mocked interface (`_handler` field):

```
string secondUser = _handler.GetTwoUserName(...)
```

I suspect the first test registers the `_handler` and never clean it up properly, so that the **same instance** appears in the second test. You should reset the `ObjectFactory` between tests following the [Register Resolve Release](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasepattern/) pattern.

Another (preferable) option is to refactor your SUT to receive the `IManager handler` dependency explicitly via [constructor](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). That would simplify both SUT and tests moving the `ObjectFactory` configuration to the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Comment: Ok, so how to I reset the factory?  That would be the answer to the question that I am looking for.

Comment: I looked up the factory dispose method, and added it to my question.  Even with that addition, I am still having the same issue.

Comment: What is `x` and what is `Handle` in the Setup method? Is any of them static?

Comment: The code above has been updated.  x was a lambda expression in ObjectFactory.Initialize.  ObjectFactory from my understanding would be static.

Comment: What about `Handler`? Is it static?

Comment: No. It is not static. ObjectFactory should be the only thing that is static.

Comment: It's still not clear for me where the `Handler` is taken from in this line: `x.For(IManager)().Use(Handler)();`